# Is there an easy way to develop with Swing Application Framework (JSR 296) AND Jython?

Tags: swing, frameworks, jython, jsr296

I'm learning Jython.
I developed a simple Swing Application with Jython and it's ok.
Now I would to use the Swing Application Framework (JSR 296).

I did not find any example in Internet.

Answer (score 0):

See the following article:

http://java.dzone.com/news/jsr-296-end-jframe